# How to remove validation focus in particular validation control

Tags: c#, asp.net

i discover final line's validation has higher priority than i set focus of first line's validation control even when i set focus it code behind.

want to disable some validation focus

discover even if i  SetFocusOnError="false" on some validation, it still not scroll to the top of page

after testing several times, most of time success, having a few cases failed. I am not sure whether someone doing things in the production site at the same time. i have already used all my methods.

i discover one thing in production site, when scroll down to the bottom page, i have to press twice submit button in order to focus to the top of page,

however when not scroll to the bottom of page, it do not focus to the top of page, just sometimes lucky it focus, most of cases it do not focus to the top of page

**Firefox and internet explorer 100% success using this method, 
Chrome  sometimes success and most of time failed in this case**

However, i still can not set focus in code behind

Answer (score 0):

finally, i set focus on textbox rather than label, it success in production site.
conclusion is that failed to set focus on label in chrome in production site and only success in testing site